# Start an HTML5 video at a particular position when it's played?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get my videos to play on different parts when the mouse hovers over them but I can't seem to get it working. I already added the script and have tested the page on different browsers.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title id="titulo">Documento sin título</title>
<link href="Estilos/estilo_tareavids.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
        document.getElementById('video1').currentTime=5;



    </script>
</head>

<body>
<header><center>VIDEOS</center></header>        
<div id="caja1"><center><video id="video1" src="Videos/Keep Away _ Star Wars Blips.mp4" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('video1').play();" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('video1').pause();"   > </video></center> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add #t=[(start_time), (end_time)] to the end of your media URL.

```
<div id="caja1"><center><video id="video1" src="Videos/Keep Away _ Star Wars Blips.mp4" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('video1').play();" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('video1').pause();"   > </video></center> </div>
```

to

```
<div id="caja1"><center><video id="video1" src="Videos/Keep Away _ Star Wars Blips.mp4#t=5,7" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('video1').play();" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('video1').pause();"   > </video></center> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You put this line in the `<head>`:

```
document.getElementById('video1').currentTime = 5;
```

which is executed before the rest of HTML is read and rendered, so it cannot find your `<video>` tag and fails.

You can either move it to below the `<video>` tag like this:

```
<header>
  <center>VIDEOS</center>
</header>
<div id="caja1">
  <center><video id="video1" src="Videos/Keep Away _ Star Wars Blips.mp4" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('video1').play();" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('video1').pause();"> </video></center>
</div>
<script>
  document.getElementById('video1').currentTime = 5;
</script>
```

Or you can execute it once the HTML document is rendered by using the `onload` event like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title id="titulo">Documento sin título</title>
  <link href="Estilos/estilo_tareavids.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
    document.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById('video1').currentTime = 5;
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <center>VIDEOS</center>
  </header>
  <div id="caja1">
    <center><video id="video1" src="Videos/Keep Away _ Star Wars Blips.mp4" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('video1').play();" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('video1').pause();"> </video></center>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```